# Why does libc depend on ld.so?

Tags: c, linux, glibc, dynamic-linking

I always think that libc should be an independent dynamic library, until I find this:

```sh
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd743c00000)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc75f4000)
```

Can someone tell me why libc needs ld.so and what function it uses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ld.so`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) is needed by any application or shared library that is linked with shared libraries:

> The programs `ld.so` and `ld-linux.so*` find and load the shared
> objects (shared libraries) needed by a program, prepare the
> program to run, and then run it.

Applications don't normally invoke any functions from `ld-linux-x86-64.so`, rather it loads the executable and shared libraries and passes the control flow to the application, which is normally C and C++ library runtime initialization code. Such a dependency on `ld-linux.so*` is established with `.interp` section of ELF file (see `readelf -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` output) and that is not what `ldd` shows.

`ldd`, however, (recursively) shows libraries marked as `NEEDED` in dynamic section (see `readelf -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` output). On Linux, thread local storage support for shared libraries is implemented by `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. That is an implementation detail, but is the reason glibc depends on ld-linux-x86-64.so.

Comment: It is useful to add that shared binaries generally refer to `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` as their interpreter. The kernel will execute a binary by reading the entry point and interpreter from the ELF binary, and then decide on how to call it. The interpreter is being called and fed with the name and file permissions of the original binary. The library loader /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 then loads all dependencies and jumps to the entry point of the dynamic binary.

Comment: So the shared libraries that do not use thread local storage won't use `ld-linux.so` as a `DT_NEED`, right?

Comment: @yhdang As I mentioned, glibc links ld-linux-x86-64.so because the latter resolves unresolved symbols in glibc, _some_ of which handle TLS. Not using TLS doesn't change that.